# how to get sendgrid user id after saving contact by using their API

Tags: php, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates, sendgrid-api-v2

I am using SendGrid API to save contacts and it returns only "job_id" that's operation is successful but I need a user_id after saving the contact to save in our local DB.
There is another API to search the contact by their email but the main problem is that the contact data is populated after a few seconds on the SendGrid dashboard and this search API returns 0 results at that time and if we hit this search API after some time then it returns results but I wanted to get user_id at the same time of inserting contacts.

Is there any other way that we can use to get the user_id after saving the contact in SendGrid?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From my reading of the API documentation, there isn't. You have to:

- Import the contact
- [Check the import job status](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/contacts/import-contacts-status)
- If the job status is set to "completed", then you can [retrieve the contact using their email address](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/contacts/get-contacts-by-emails)

I appreciate that this isn't what you're after, but thought it worth mentioning all the same.

I created [a small repo](https://github.com/settermjd/sendgrid-import-retrieve-with-php) showing how to import and retrieve a contact if that's of help.